# What does "sequence" mean in this context?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I don't understand how the word "sequence" is defined in the excerpt below.

> Any permutation can be broken into cycles. For example,
>   $$ P = \left( \begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 5 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 1 \end{array} \right) = (156)(23)(4).$$
>   Suppose a permutation contains $C_\nu$ cycles of length $\nu$, where $\sum _\nu \nu C_\nu = N$.
>
> (snip)
>
> , consider the case of $N = 6, C_1 = 3, C_3 = 1, C_2 = C_4 = C_5 = C_6 = 0$. An example is the permutation $P = (5)(3)(2)(461)$. Notice that the **sequence** $Q = 5,3,2,4,6,1$ corresponds to $P$. In other words, from the **sequence** $Q$, we can uniquely construct the permutation $P$ with $C_1 = 3$, $C_3 = 1$. But from $Q' = 2,5,3,4,6,1$, or from $Q'' = 5,3,2,1,4,6$, we can also construct in the same way the same $P$.
>
> (*Statistical Mechanics a set of lectures, Richard P. Feynman, p.62-63*)

I'm suspecting that sequence $q$ is defined with $\{C_\nu\}$ so that "a latter set of digits forms a longer cycle". For example,

$$ q \equiv 1,2,3,4,5,6\ \ \  \text{is without doubt interpreted as}\ \ \ (12)(3456)\ \ \ \text{when}\ \ \ C_2 = 2, C_4 = 1 .$$

In this case, $3,4,5,6$ is the last set of digits so this corresponds to the longest cycle of length $4$. On the other hand, $1, 2$ appears on the left of $3,4,5,6$, so these form a shorter (here, shortest) cycle of length $2$. Another example:

$$ q\ \ \ \text{is interpreted as}\ \ \ (123)(456)\ \ \ \text{when}\ \ \ C_3 = 2,$$ 
$$ \text{and is interpreted as}\ \ \ (1)(23)(456)\ \ \ \text{when}\ \ \ C_1 = 1, C_2 = 1, C_3 = 1.$$

I've been reading the book from the first page, and just encountered the excerpt today. There is no chance I overlooked the definition. So it should be the general and common definition in the world of math.

Does anyone have definition of "sequence" which is consistent with the explanation above?

---

Supplement:

Please note that there two $P$s appeared in the excerpt but, in the context of $Q$'s definition, only the latter $P = (5)(3)(2)(461)$ is living because only this $P$ fullfills

> (, consider the case of $N = 6,) C_1 = 3, C_3 = 1, C_2 = C_4 = C_5 = C_6 = 0$.

If I could use the definition of former $P = (156)(23)(4)$, I would easily understand a sentence like

> $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is mapped to a sequence $q = 5,3,2,4,6,1$ by $p = (4)(23)(156)$.

But, in real, $P$ is $(5)(3)(2)(461)$. I think this $P$ results in a sequence $4,2,3,6,5,1$ which is clearly different from $Q = 5,3,2,4,6,1$.

Comment: Isn't an example such as $5,3,2,1,4,6$ not explicit enough ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence

Comment: @YvesDaoust An array $[1,2,3,4,5,6]$ is mapped to $[4,2,3,6,5,1]$ by a function $P = (5)(3)(2)(461)$. This is different from $Q = 5,3,2,4,6,1, Q'$ and $Q''$, I think. Is this consistent?

Comment: You asked what a sequence is. I told you.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I asked what a sequence is **in this context**. I don't think the usual definition is consistent with the context (please see my update). I'm sorry if what I'm saying is strange as I'm not familiar with math.

Comment: In this context, it is used with its standard, neutral meaning. You are trying to map an interpretation that is not relevant.

Comment: So function $P = (5)(3)(2)(461)$ corresponds to $Q = 5,3,2,4,6,1$ as explained in the excerpt?

Comment: I don't know. I am just confirming you that $5,3,2,4,6,1$ is a sequence.

Comment: Yes. $5,3,2,4,6,1$ is a sequence. However, just referring to this fact does not take the context into account, doesn't it? The excerpt says "sequence $Q = 5,3,2,4,6,1$ corresponds to $P$". I'm afraid you answered only the first part of this sentence.

Comment: I answered the very question "What does “sequence” mean in this context?"

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you. The link was helpful. By that, I could learn the standard definition which I think is not consistent with the usage in the excerpt for the reason written in the question. I should have titled this post as "Is the definition of a word "sequence" in this excerpt consistent with the standard definition? And why?". The phrase "in the context" was too vague, maybe?

Comment: I have no idea where you see an inconsistency with the standard definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Let me write my interpretation. A sequence is (narrowly) defined as a map $f: \{1,2,3,4,\cdots\} \to \mathbb{N}$. In the excerpt, the permutation $P$ corresponds to this map $f$. For example, for $P = (1)(23)$, the map is $P(1) = 1, P(2) = 3, P(3) = 2$ and thus this $P$ corresponds to a sequence $1,3,2$. Similarly, $P = (5)(3)(2)(461)$ results in a sequence $4,2,3,5,6,1$. However, the excerpt says $Q = 5,3,2,4,6,1$ and $Q' = 2,5,3,4,6,1$ and $Q'' = 5,3,2,1,4,6$ are all corresponds to $P = (5)(3)(2)(461)$. I don't understand why. What point did I make a mistake?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the definition of a sequence. $Q,Q'$ and $Q''$ are distinct sequences and sequences do not need to be permutations of anything. $3, 3, 3, 1, 3,3$ is a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you consider the permutation as a bijection $\sigma$ from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to itself, what the author calls 'sequence' is simply
$$Q=\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\ldots,\sigma(6)$$

Comment: Could you please see my edit?

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of, say, real numbers is a map $f\colon I\to \Bbb R$ where $I$ is either the set $\Bbb N$ of natural numbers (inifnite sequence) or an initial segment $\{\,k\in\Bbb N\mid k<N\,\}$ thereof (finite sequence). The more suggestive notation $5,3,2,4,6,1$ stands for the sequence $f\colon\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\to \Bbb R$ where $f(1)=5$, $f(2)=3$, and so on.

Comment: $f(1) = 5, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 2, f(4) = 4, f(5) = 6, f(6) = 1$, so $f$ is permutation $(4)(23)(156)$? But in the excerpt, this is interpreted as $(5)(3)(2)(461)$.